# Test Lambda function with secrets locally without AWS secrets manager

Tags: python, docker, lambda

I have code like this

```
Unix = 'linux'
Mac = 'darwin'
if sys.platform == Unix
   do this
elif sys.platform == Mac
   do this
```

I have this check for sys platform because aws is unix based, and therefore if sys.platform = 'Mac'
then I am running locally.

I'm running into trouble when I try to dockerize this application because the dockerized build is linux based,
so in this if-else statement, the build will run the 1st
part of the if-else even though I'm building the docker
container locally.

Is it possible to set the sys.platform in a dockerfile?

edit:

**Problem Statement:**

Trying to dockerize an aws lambda function. To do so, I need
to test the lambda function locally.

My lamba function composition looks like this:

```
app
    lambda_function1
        database.py
        helper.py
functions
    lambda_function1.py
```

The main purpose of this lambda function is to read data
from the production database, and then predict some value
based on the data.

```
database.py
    import helper
    ...
    class DB:
        def __init__(self):
            self.secrets = helper.get_secrets()
            self.db_name = self.secrets.get('DB', '')
            self.db_host = self.secrets.get('Host', '')
            self.db_password = self.secrets.get('Password', '')
        ...
```

```
helper.py
    import sys
    import boto3
    ....
    def get_secrets():
        secrets = {}
        if sys.platform == constants.MAC_PLATFORM:
            secrets = local_secrets()
            return secrets
        session = boto3.session.Session()
        client = session.client(service_name='secretsmanager',
                                region_name='us-west-2')
        secrets = get_aws_secrets()
```

As you can see, if sys platform is 'darwin',
then the secrets will be local secrets.
If sys platform is 'linux', then the secrets will be secrets pulled
from aws.

For some reason, I am unable to connect to the database with the aws
secrets in my local docker build due to a tcp/ip error.
I think this is due to some weird configuration issue that I don't have locally that aws might have, therefore I would like to start by working with the local database in docker, and use the get_local_secrets method
to obtain secrets.

Any ideas?

Comment: AWS has windows machines as well... But maybe you should show what specifically needs to be done differently between Mac or Unix? Or why you need Docker to think its a Mac when it is run in AWS?

Comment: Your platform checks aren't correct. `sys.platform` on mac is `darwin`, and on linux it's... well... `linux`. But in a docker container, the platform will most likely be `linux`. Why do you want to have docker pretend it is a mac?

Comment: @C.Nivs I want to have docker pretend its a mac for local testing purposes

Comment: As noted above, the platform inside the container is always Linux. If you want to be able to run that container locally and know that it's being run locally why not use a command line argument or an environment variable you can check in your code? So you'd run something like `docker run my_container --local_test` or something.

Comment: Can you show *exactly* what you are trying to do? This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @C.Nivs Updated

Comment: Updated the title for what you actually are asking, but if you needed to mock AWS secretsmanager, this could help https://github.com/localstack/localstack

Comment: Another solution could be a try-except around the boto-client, then fallback to some environment variables

Comment: @OneCricketeer That might be a better solution that the accepted one for me since connecting to a real database takes forever. I just need to mock the database return values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the environment variable suggestion and run locally by setting some values at runtime:

```py
import os

if os.environ.get('LOCAL_TEST', 'false').lower().strip() == 'true':
    secrets = local_secrets()
else:
    # use aws secrets
```

And run your container like:

```sh
docker run -e LOCAL_TEST=true your_image
```

Comment: I'd do `if bool(os.environ.get('LOCAL_TEST'))`

Comment: @OneCricketeer sure, that works. I think setting it to some bool-ish variable in the config might be a touch more readable, but that's subjective

Comment: why do you lower and strip?

Comment: @coderboi in case it reads in a newline or someone puts `True` by accident